# Scala: Resolving ambiguous types for pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I asked an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820071/scala-restricting-ordered-comparison-in-subclasses-to-the-same-subclass) to which I received a great answer. In the comments, Travis mentioned that comparing two `HandValue`s wouldn't work directly, but pattern matching could be used to ensure comparing the same class.

```
  sealed abstract class HandValue[T <: HandValue[T]](val rank: Int) extends Ordered[T]
  case class HighCard(high: Int) extends HandValue[HighCard](0){
    def compare(that: HighCard) = this.high - that.high
  }

  case class TwoPair(high: Int, big: Int, sm: Int) extends HandValue[TwoPair](2) {
    def compare (that: TwoPair) = { ... }
  }
```

In the attempted pattern matching below, I have a compile-time error that I suspect has to do with using `HandValue[_]`. `val h1: HandValue[T <: HandValue[T]]`, similar to how the type was declared, isn't valid. Is there a way to resolve these?

```
  val ans = sessions count {
    hands: (Hand, Hand) => {
      val h1: HandValue[_] = handValue(hands._1)
      val h2: HandValue[_] = handValue(hands._2)
      (h1, h2) match { // <-- Line as source of error
        case _ if h1.rank > h2.rank => true
        case (a: HighCard, b: HighCard) => a > b
        case (a: TwoPair, b: TwoPair) => a > b
        // etc..
      }
    }
  }
```

Edit: The compile-time error is:

```
error: type arguments [_$3] do not conform to class HandValue's type parameter bounds [T <: euler.solutions.p54.HandValue[T]]
(h1, h2) match {
```

Edit 2: As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025815/how-to-define-case-classes-with-members-with-unbound-type-parameters), using `Type[_]` won't work.

Comment: What is the compile time error?

Comment: Ah sorry, good call! I forgot to paste it in.

Comment: BTW, what is the relation between Hand and HandValue?

Comment: `type Hand = Array[Card]` where `Card` has `c.suit` and `c.value`, and then a `HandValue` is computed using the properties of the Array -- for example, if for `Hand h`, `h.forall(_.suit == h(0).suit)`, then it has `HandValue` subclass of `Flush`.

Comment: Are you writing a bot? )

Comment: No, it's [Project Euler 54](http://projecteuler.net/problem=54)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't help with the error, but you could remove a lot of this complexity by allowing any `HandValue` to be compared to any other `HandValue`; then you don't have to have that horrendous parameterization and repeated `compare` methods, followed by the repeated comparison logic in `ans`.

One way would be to have each one define a `strength`, which is a `Seq[Int]` consisting of the hand rank followed by the ranks of the cards within the hand that define its strength. Then you just compare these `Seqs` by finding which has a larger number coming first, i.e.

```
sealed abstract class HandValue(val strength: Seq[Int]) extends Ordered[HandValue] {
  import math.Ordering.Implicits.seqDerivedOrdering
  def compare(that: HandValue) = 
    Ordering[Seq[Int]].compare(this.strength, that.strength)
}

case class HighCard(high1: Int, high2: Int, high3: Int, high4: Int, high5: Int ) 
  extends HandValue(Seq(0, high1, high2, high3, high4, high5))

case class TwoPair(high: Int, big: Int, sm: Int) 
  extends HandValue(Seq(2, big, sm, high))

val ans = sessions count { hands => 
  handValue(hands._1) > handValue(hands._2)
}
```

Note, you need to take all the cards into account when calculating a high card hand strength. Also look out for the Ace-to-5 straight!

You could also just calculate the `strength` as an `Int` using a hashing function (as I did when I did this problem: https://gist.github.com/3270831).

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to what you suggested -- thanks!